# How do I correctly implement Java animations?

Tags: java

Here's what I have so far.

```
//Inside the Animations class
public void update() {
    timer +=System.currentTimeMillis() - lastTime;
    lastTime = System.currentTimeMillis();

    if(timer>speed) {
        Playing=true;
        index++;

        timer=0;
        if(index>=frames.length) {
            index = 0;
            Playing=false;
        }
    }

}//Getters and setters down
```

In the main state

```
    @Override
public void update() {
    Ability.update();
        if(AttackP.isPlaying()) {
            AttackP.update();

        }

    //gets
    HealthCheck();
    getMousePosition();
}
```

...

```
    if(turn==true) {//Only run when it's the players turn
        if(MousePressed&&!AttackP.isPlaying()&&!AttackingP) {
//if left clicked when animations are not playing and when AttackingP is false
            buttonCheck(g);//next
        }else if(!MousePressed) {//set Attacking to false when mouse not pressed
            AttackingP=false;
        }
```

...

```
private void buttonCheck(Graphics g) {
    if(MouseX<501&&MouseX>420&&MouseY<531&&MouseY>500){//if the mouse is in this button

        AttackingP=true;
        StartAnimation(g);

        }
```

...

```
    private void StartAnimation(Graphics g) {

    g.drawImage(getCurrentAnimationFrame(),175,0,512/2,512/2, null);//play animation
    BossHealth-=5;
    turn=false;

}

public BufferedImage getCurrentAnimationFrame(){
    return AttackP.getCurrentFrame();
    }
```

The problem is, when I press the button, the animation only renders 1 frame, not the others in the BufferedImage array.

Help appreciated, I've been stuck on this part for 2 days now.

Comment: I'm guessing the first code block's `index` is used in `AttackP.getCurrentFrame()` in the last code block?  Also have you tried any form of debugging?  I've found putting print statements in places like updating the index and getting the current frame to be very effective

Comment: Also it appears you only draw the button `StartAnimation`, called by `buttonCheck`, you may also want to have `update` or something similar redraw the button when it's time for the next frame